# "[error] [upstream] connection timed out after 10 seconds" failed when fluent-bit tries to communicate with fluentd in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, fluent-bit

I'm using fluent-bit to collect logs and pass it to fluentd for processing in a Kubernetes environment. Fluent-bit instances are controlled by DaemonSet and read logs from docker containers.

```
      [INPUT]
      Name tail
      Path /var/log/containers/*.log
      Parser docker
      Tag kube.*
      Mem_Buf_Limit 5MB
      Skip_Long_Lines On
```

There is a fluent-bit service also running

```
Name:              monitoring-fluent-bit-dips
Namespace:         dips
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/instance=monitoring
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=fluent-bit-dips
                   app.kubernetes.io/version=1.8.10
                   helm.sh/chart=fluent-bit-0.19.6
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: monitoring
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: dips
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=monitoring,app.kubernetes.io/name=fluent-bit-dips
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.43.72.32
IPs:               <none>
Port:              http  2020/TCP
TargetPort:        http/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.144:2020,10.42.1.155:2020,10.42.2.186:2020 + 1 more...
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Fluentd service description is as below

```
Name:              monitoring-logservice
Namespace:         dips
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/instance=monitoring
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=logservice
                   app.kubernetes.io/version=1.9
                   helm.sh/chart=logservice-0.1.2
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: monitoring
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: dips
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=monitoring,app.kubernetes.io/name=logservice
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.43.44.254
IPs:               <none>
Port:              http  24224/TCP
TargetPort:        http/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.143:24224
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

But fluent-bit logs doesn't reach fluentd and getting following error

```
[error] [upstream] connection #81 to monitoring-fluent-bit-dips:24224 timed out after 10 seconds
```

I tried several things like;

- re-deploying fluent-bit pods
- re-deploy fluentd pod
- Upgrade fluent-bit version from 1.7.3 to 1.8.10

This is an Kubernetes environment where fluent-bit able to communicate with fluentd in the very earlier stage of deployment. Apart from that, this same fluent versions is working when I deploy locally with docker-desktop environment.

My guesses are

- fluent-bit cannot manage the amount of log process
- fluent services are unable to communicate once the services are restarted

Anyone having any experience in this or has any idea how to debug this issue more deeper?

---

Updated following with fluentd running pod description

```
Name:         monitoring-logservice-5b8864ffd8-gfpzc
Namespace:    dips
Priority:     0
Node:         sl-sy-k3s-01/10.16.1.99
Start Time:   Mon, 29 Nov 2021 13:09:13 +0530
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=monitoring
              app.kubernetes.io/name=logservice
              pod-template-hash=5b8864ffd8
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2021-11-29T12:37:23+05:30
Status:       Running
IP:           10.42.0.143
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.0.143
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/monitoring-logservice-5b8864ffd8
Containers:
  logservice:
    Container ID:   containerd://102483a7647fd2f10bead187eddf69aa4fad72051d6602dd171e1a373d4209d7
    Image:          our.private.repo/dips/logservice/splunk:1.9
    Image ID:       our.private.repo/dips/logservice/splunk@sha256:531f15f523a251b93dc8a25056f05c0c7bb428241531485a22b94896974e17e8
    Ports:          24231/TCP, 24224/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 29 Nov 2021 13:09:14 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       exec [/bin/healthcheck.sh] delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      exec [/bin/healthcheck.sh] delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      SOME_ENV_VARS
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from monitoring-logservice-token-g9kwt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  monitoring-logservice-token-g9kwt:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  monitoring-logservice-token-g9kwt
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: There's only one Fluentd pod in your question, can you `kubectl describe` this pod and post the complete output in your question?

Comment: @gohm'c is there any specific details that you want to see? Since it is more than 50 lines.

Comment: No worry about the lines, just post it.

Answer (score 1):

Try change your fluent-bit config that points to fluentd service as **monitoring-logservice.dips:24224**

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/kubernetes

```
  filters: |
    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default:443
        tls.verify Off
```

In my issue, Kubernetes Apiserver ssl error.